# How much code is too much?

Tags: discussion, support, underhanded

The other day I had idea on how to troll my colleague, which was "underhand bejeweled" - favorite procrastination tool for both of us. And the idea is basically "program me bejeweled which cannot be lost"

Being pretty junior programmer myself, I have idea that

1. I cannot complete it myself
2. If I ask it here as underhand challenge, the code output would be pretty huge

So, long story short:

How much code challenge for underhand is too much? And would that question be on-topic here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"program me bejeweled which cannot be lost" is *very* broad and is likely to be closed as "too broad".

You can make it less broad though, by adding more specification, for example:

- Specify how you cannot lose, for example: by using cheat codes, by giving optimal tiles (and specify 'optimal tiles') ...
- Specify how the graphics should look like: ASCII, images ...

You'll also have to specify the winning criterion: for a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), you need to have a very clear spec. If it's a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), you should still leave some room for creativity, but keep in mind that it should be a *programming* contest and not a "build the best game" contest.

I suggest posting your challenge in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/9275), then people can comment on it and suggest improvements before the challenge gets posted on the main site.